# Handling a parameter in a model definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following request

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", [...], "balance"=>"2", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile[...]
```

Is meant to process a file, whose processing is defined in a model

```
def self.import(file)
  Rails.logger.info @balance
  CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => "\t", :quote_char => "\x00", headers: false) do |row|
```

However, this model needs to access the `balance` parameter as a global value.

The logger registers a blank for `@balance`.  The controller attempts to pass this information to the model in the following manner

```
def import
  @balance = request.params[:balance]
  Importportfolio.import(params[:file])
```

How can the model effectively use this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send it with the method call.

```
def import
  @balance = request.params[:balance]
  Importportfolio.import(params[:file], @balance)
  ...
```

Then in the model

```
def self.import(file, balance)
  ...
```

Then in the model, you would reference it as `balance` not `@balance`, just to be clear